# How can I override BorderBrush?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I have a style to a textbox, and I want in the application layer override de BorderBrush of this style.

I tried: d:LayoutOverrides="BorderBrush". But this doesn't work.

I want the same style, but with a red BorderBrush.

How can I do this please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

as you mentioned Blend in your tags: you can right-click a textbox search templates and create new ones from the existing (Edit a Copy). This will extract the complete definition of the textbox and you can change everything you want there.

Here is everything explained step-by-step: [Create or edit a control template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294908.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Base your style on your old one and change the Border brush

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource oldBrushKey}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

or if it's the default style you want to override use

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"
```

Comment: it seems awesome, but I don't know why, it is not working. The border is not changing.

Comment: I have this line inside the style that I want to base on:
<Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="0,0,0,-2.667" BorderBrush="#FFC2C2C2">. This is inside a <Setter Property="Template">. I want to change that borderbrush!

Comment: So I take it, putting the same thing inside the new style but changing the border brush doesn't work?